# Integrating moving, common background image for carousel page in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, carousel

I'm trying to integrate a common wide background image for Xamarin Forms Carousel page. As the requirement I need to smoothly change the visible part of the image according to changes of child pages (Ex. moving the visible part of the theme background image of a mobile phone when moving the menu pages). Is there any way to achieve this approach.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb SO's [recommendations addressed to new users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You may take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour); then do read what's [on-topic here] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). In your case, e.g. start with the sample in [Xamarin.Forms CarouselView Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/layout) and, when the sample, works, try to modify.

Comment: Hi can you elaborate your question? Some screenshot or representations will help to understand the question